# Should there be Anonymous Comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, down-votes

I currently got a downvote for my question [Making a Graph Eulerian for Applying TSP Heuristics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313371/making-a-graph-eulerian-for-applying-tsp-heuristics), but unfortunately the downvoter didn't leave a comment explaining what the motivation was, thus depriving me the chance to address the issue(s).

My assumption is that downvoters are hesitant to leave comments because the fear negative feelings or impacts on their own postings.

Would it be an option to allow anonymous comments, where the identity of the commenter isn't publicly visible? As the identity would be known to the moderators, it would still be possible to ban insulting comments.

I would like to hear what others think about anonymous comments; maybe there is experience from other forums, that offer such an option, which can be shared.

Comment: The following feature request on Meta Stack Exchange (from 2009) is tagged ([meta-tag:status-declined]): [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6521) (Of course, you can also have a look at other discussions [linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6521) to see whether you find something interesting there.)

Comment: This is only tangentially related, but the questions whether downvotes should in general be accompanied by a comment has also been discussed a few times. Here are two links from this meta (and links to some discussion on other metas can be found there): [Completely Unexplained Downvotes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/398) and [Can anyone learn anything from a downvote without an accompanying rationale in a comment?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3512)

Comment: @MartinSleziak the dicussion Meta Stack Exchange is quite thorough and addresses most of the points. So if there aren't strong arguments in favor of anyomous comments in reply to this question, it can be closed.

Comment: A comment is a comment, and a vote is a vote -- these are two separate things. -- Or would you want to give an explanation each time you vote on a post, be it up or down?

Comment: @StefanKohl maybe not on upvvotes, but certainly on a downvote, simply because I see that as a kind of politeness that may improve on the  reputation of the MO community.

Comment: I used to leave comments when I voted things down, and it really really really ticked people off.

Comment: I think there had been several posts about unexplained/uncomprehensible downvotes on meta in the past. How about disabling downvotes at all?